# CSS Media Query is affecting other queries also

Tags: css, media-queries

Below are the media queries i have figured out and i will use as default for every project that i will do.

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {}
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {}
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {}
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {}
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {}
```

Now, the problem i am facing with them is that when i try to change something on 768 it gets changed on 320 also. I want to change for example logo if i hide it on 768 it should only be invisible on 768 only, whereas in this case i have to manually go on each and every query and make it visible.

I have tried `min-width` also and `max-width` also.
And `min-width` for mobile size and `max-width` for big sizes but with no luck.

And if i use fixed queries then also i have to write code for every query.

So, how do i make it work only for single size and does not affect the others, and most importantly not to write code for every size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    // applied  only between 767 px and 480px
}
```

Comment: I will give you +1 if you change it to 480 and 767 (767 = 768 - 1)

Comment: Thanx @NoelWidmer and @Shelly but if i don't go with RANGE queries and only use `min` or `max` at a time. In that situation how do i stop any class or id merging with other queries.

Comment: @SoebSafi You need multiple queries like 1.(max = 99) 2. (min = 100; max = 499) 3. (min = 500) if you still have problems you may need to consider making a good use of "!important"

Comment: Okay @NoelWidmer got it. Let me give it a shot, thanx for your time.

Comment: @SoebSafi Good spirit! Media queries are always stronger than normal css (If no !important is used). The only real issue should be if you set the css in multiple media queries at the same time (Then the order of your media queries comes into play) OR if you have an inline rule, which can only be overwritten with !important I belive.

Answer (score 2):

It will, To avoid that you need to write specific for all the resolutions below to that. For example: If you are hiding logo in 768 then it affects 480, 320,. To get rid of that you need to write in 480, that the specific logo to be visible, so that it will be reflected in 320 too.

```
/* #### CSS that's applied when the viewing area's width is 768px or less #### */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){    

  div#logo{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

For logo to be visible in 480 and 320 try like this:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 480){        

      div#logo{
        display: none;
      }
    }
```

For more info, **[Reference link](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries.shtml)**

Comment: Thanx @K.B.BM so there is no alternative but to write specific code for a query that is being affected.